# How to scatter multiple variables in an array for MPI_Scatter

Tags: arrays, c, parallel-processing, mpi, scatter

I am currently struggling to equally distribute an array with 8 integers to 2 integers *per* 4 processors. I used `MPI_Bcast` to let every processors to know there are total array of 8 and each of those will have 2 integers array called "my_input".

```
MPI_Bcast(&totalarray,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Bcast(&my_input,2,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Scatter (input, 2 , MPI_INT, &my_input, 2 , MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
//MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD);
printf("\n my input is %d & %d and rank is  %d \n" , my_input[0], my_input[1] , rank);
```

However after scattering, I see the print function cannot print the 'rank' but all the integers from the 8 integers array. How should I program in order to equally distribute the number of arrays to other processors from root?

Here is my full code (it is just for testing a total of 8 integers, therefore scanf I will enter '8'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//initailise MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    //Variable to identify processor and total number of processors
    int rank, size;
    int my_input[0];

    //initailse total array variable
    int totalarray =0;

    //initialise memory array
    int* input;

    //range of random number
    int upper = 100, lower = 0;

    //declare processor rank
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    //declare total size of processor
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);


    //let root gather N elements from user
    if (rank == 0)
    {
        printf("Enter a number from 1 to 1000: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        int number;

        //ask user to input number of elements
        scanf("%d",&number);
        printf("Your number is %d\n",number);

        //Fill the array to power of 2
        int totalarray = pow(2, ceil(log(number)/log(2)));

        input[totalarray];
        my_input[totalarray/size];

        //allocate memory for the array
        input = malloc(totalarray * sizeof(int) );

        //Add randomise number until N elements
        for(int i =0; i<=totalarray ; i++)
        {
            if( i<number)
            {
                input[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower; ;
            }
            //padding zero to the extra elements
            else if(number <= i < totalarray)
            {
                input[i] = 0;
            }
        }

        //confirm the input array
        printf("the input is: ");

          for(int i =0; i < totalarray ; i++)
        {
          printf(  "%d  ", input[i]);
        }

    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&totalarray,1,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Bcast(&my_input,2,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    MPI_Scatter (input, 2 , MPI_INT, &my_input, 2 , MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    //MPI_Barrier (MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    printf("\n my input is %d & %d and rank is  %d \n" , my_input[0], my_input[1] , rank);


    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used MPI_Bcast to let every processors to know there are total array
> of 8 and each of those will have 2 integers array called "my_input".

Yes, that makes sense.

> However after scattering, I see the print function cannot print the
> 'rank' but all the integers from the 8 integers array. How should I
> program in order to equally distribute the number of arrays to other
> processors from root?

You have some issues with your code. For instance, you declare the variables `my_input`, `totalarray`, and `input` as:

```
int my_input[0];
...
int totalarray =0;
...
int* input;
```

and then within `if (rank == 0)` you redefine them again:

```
int totalarray = pow(2, ceil(log(number)/log(2)));
input[totalarray];
my_input[totalarray/size];
input = malloc(totalarray * sizeof(int) );
```

This is not correct, alternatively what you can do is to declare both arrays as `int*`, namely:

```
int *my_input;
int *input;
```

then allocate their space as soon as you know how many elements there will be in each of those arrays.

The `input` array can be allocated right after the user has inserted the size of that array:

```
   //ask user to input number of elements
    scanf("%d",&number);
    printf("Your number is %d\n",number);
    input = malloc(totalarray * sizeof(int));
```

and the `my_input` array after the *master* process has broadcast the input size to the other processes:

```
MPI_Bcast(&totalarray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
int *my_input = malloc((totalarray/size) * sizeof(int));
```

For the variable `totalarray` just do not declare again within `if (rank == 0)`. Because if you do so, then `int totalarray = pow(2, ceil(log(number)/log(2)));` will be a different variable that will only exist in the scope of the `if (rank == 0)`.

The second `MPI_Bcast` call

```
MPI_Bcast(&my_input,2,MPI_INT,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

is unless, since you want to

> **to equally distribute** total 8 integers in an array to 2 integers for
> 4 processors.

and not that every process has the entire contend of the `my_input` array of the *master* process.

For that you need the `MPI_Scatter` which you do. However, instead of

```
  MPI_Scatter (input, 2 , MPI_INT, &my_input, 2 , MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
```

do not hardcode the size of the inputs, because if you want to test with different input sizes and/or with a different number of processes the code will not work, do the following instead:

```
  int size_per_process = totalarray/size;
  MPI_Scatter (input, size_per_process , MPI_INT, my_input, size_per_process , MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
```

The loop `for(int i =0; i<=totalarray ; i++)` should actually be `for(int i =0; i< totalarray ; i++)`, otherwise you are getting out of boundaries of the array `input`. Personal opinion, but I think that the adding of the random values logic reads better this way:

```
    for(int i =0; i < number ; i++)
       input[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower; 
    for(int i = number; i < totalarray; i++)
       input[i] = 0;
```

The final code would look like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank, size;
    int *input;
    int totalarray;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0){
        printf("Enter a number from 1 to 1000: ");
        fflush(stdout);

        int number;
        scanf("%d",&number);
        printf("Your number is %d\n",number);

        totalarray = pow(2, ceil(log(number)/log(2)));

        input = malloc(totalarray * sizeof(int));
         
        int upper = 100, lower = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < number ; i++)
           input[i] = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
        for(int i = number; i < totalarray; i++)
           input[i] = 0;

        printf("the input is: ");
        for(int i =0; i < totalarray ; i++)
           printf(  "%d  ", input[i]);
    }
    
    MPI_Bcast(&totalarray, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    int size_per_process = totalarray / size;
    int *my_input = malloc(size_per_process * sizeof(int));
    printf("SIZE PER %d\n", size_per_process);
    MPI_Scatter (input, size_per_process, MPI_INT, my_input, size_per_process, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
    printf("\n my input is %d & %d and rank is  %d \n" , my_input[0], my_input[1] , rank);


    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The last print can also be made to be more generic by printing the entire `my_input` rather than just the first two positions.